# MySQL explain gives different results on different machines

Tags: mysql

The following query yields two different results when I run it as opposed to when a coworker runs it:

```
explain select *
from `mydatabase`.`Transactions` as `transaction`
join `mydatabase`.`Documents` as `document` on `document`.`version` = `transaction`.`documentVersion`
join `mydatabase`.`DocumentTopics` as `documentTopic` on `documentTopic`.`documentId` = `document`.`documentId`
join `mydatabase`.`Topics` on `mydatabase`.`Topics`.`id` = `documentTopic`.`topicID`
where `mydatabase`.`Topics`.`id` in (1,2)
and `transaction`.`userHash` = 'xxxxx';
```

On my machine:

[image]

On my coworkers machine:

[image]

So why is it doing a full table scan on my machine but not on my coworkers machine?

We're both using a dockerized MySQL 5.7.33 on Mac with the exact same db dump.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you certain that this behavior is completely reproducible?

Answer (score 3):

The optimizer's choice of index is based on statistics InnoDB holds for tables and indexes.

These statistics are produced periodically by InnoDB reading a random sample of pages from the table, and extrapolating things like index cardinality, so it can decide whether the index is worth using.

Occasionally the statistics are based on a skewed sampling of data, so the statistics are not representative.

I suggest you run `ANALYZE TABLE Transactions` in both MySQL containers, then try the experiment again. This statement will cause InnoDB to refresh the statistics for that table, based on a new random sample of pages.

Comment: This worked, thanks! What's the periodicity of refreshing? We had this problem for several weeks and there didn't seem to be a refresh occurring. And are there any learnings for production dbs from this? Should we perform ANALYZE TABLE for all tables periodically ourselves?

Comment: Yes, I just had to write a service at my company that runs ANALYZE TABLE for every table about every 10 days. The reason was this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75428 InnoDB automatically refreshes stats after 10% of the table rows have changed, but it turns out the counter keeping track of that is reset to 0 when mysqld restarts. I imagine in your case, dockerized MySQL would be restarted regularly, so it's possible it never stays running long enough for 10% of the rows to be changed.

Comment: In our case, we're super diligent about upgrading all our MySQL instances every time a new version comes out. So it's likely that we restart every instance at least once every 2-3 months. That combined with some tables being very large (billions of rows), it meant it was common for the counter to be reset to 0 before 10% of the table rows had changed.